# QString convert camel case to space separated words

Tags: regex, qt, qstring

I am trying to convert a camel cased QString into lowercased words separated by spaces. I currently have:

```
QString camelCase = "thisIsACamelCaseWord"
QString unCamelCase = camelCase.replace(QRegularExpression("([A-Z])", " $1")).toLower();
```

Which seems to work [here](https://regex101.com/r/vFFA51/1),

> "this Is A Camel Case Word"

but it is returning with:

> "this $1s $1 $1amel $1ase $1ord"

Comment: Since Qt is using PCRE you should also use the back reference syntax used [by pcre](https://pcre.org/original/doc/html/pcrepattern.html) - \0, \1 and so on.

Comment: @chehrlic, that made it work.

Comment: @chehrlic any chance you write a proper answer? I hate it when answer is written in comments and in a way that doesn't open up for non-experts of the topic. This would be a great point to learn about pcre and back end reference syntax but answer is only serving the OP and not others. So I'd be happy to up-vote a correct answer which teaches me something new ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since [QRegularExpression uses PRCE](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qregularexpression.html#details) the back reference syntax is '\0', '\1' and so on as explained in the [documentation](https://pcre.org/original/doc/html/pcrepattern.html).

Comment: Just to clarify, use a double backslash instead of $: `QRegularExpression("([A-Z])", " \\1")`